# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector';

Tags: python, mysql

This question has been asked before, but none of the answers from other posts solved my problem. Please do not mark it as a duplicate before reading.

When I tried to run a python program with `import mysql.connector` on an **ssh server**, the following error occurs. This error does not occur on my local machine.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    import mysql.connector
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```

I have ensured that mysql connector is correctly pip installed:

- `pip3 list` shows `mysql-connector` when called.
- I have tried `pip3 install --user mysql-connector`, `pip3 install --user mysql-connector-python`, and `pip3 install --user mysql-connector-python-rf`
- I have also tried `pip3 install --user mysql.connector`, but there is no module with this name.

As mentioned before, the program runs perfectly fine on my local machine in VS Code, but when the program is `scp`'d onto an ssh server, the program fails to run.

All my attempts in running the program are in python 3.6 (I've tried `shell>python3.6 test.py` and `shell>python3 test.py`)

I would appreciate any help possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add how you're executing the script on the remote server? It could be simply a case of it using the wrong python interpreter depending on how python is installed on the remote system.

Comment: @264nm Ah yes! I'm executing the python script with `python3.6 test.py` with `test.py` being the script

Comment: @HaruFrost Try `py -m pip install mysql-connector-python`

Comment: Also, as you have mentioned, the thing is that you may not be using the python version which has the package.

Comment: What distro is the SSH server running? I can write an answer to help debug this for you if I know your environment a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

There is a module named `mysql.py` somewhere - probably in the current working directory - that is masking the package:

```sh
$  python -c 'import mysql.connector'
$  touch mysql.py
$  python -c 'import mysql.connector'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysql.connector'; 'mysql' is not a package
```